# Duplicate active record actions for model in two databases

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

We have many clients from all around the world, and one of their requirements is to store data in USA or Europe.

To do that - one of our Model, should duplicate info in both databases (USA/Europe), which means if Model is updated, it should also fire update for second database. If new record is created, it should be created in first database, and second. So basically it should duplicate AR actions (except select) in two databases.

I have updated database.yml to store two database configurations:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8mb4
  host: 127.0.0.1
  username: xx
  password: xx
  database: _
  pool: 25

development_usa:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8mb4
  host: 127.0.0.1
  username: xx
  password: xx
  database: _usa
  pool: 25
```

And after that I logically thought to override actions as `save` http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveResource/Base/save , but knowing there are way more of doing things than one, like `.save` `.update_attribute` and seeing their source code, they all call different methods, so it is too much work to override all of these functions.

Is there a way to clone one Model in both databases after commit?

Comment: A rough idea off my head is to establish a connection with the other database. Then have an `after_commit` callback that is triggered once an operation is done in one database. This callback repeats same operation in the second database. I hope this can trigger an idea?

Comment: you can also use `after_touch` callback (an after_touch callback is triggered whenever an object is touched.)

Comment: Yeah, immediately after posting a question thought about after_commit/after_touch. will play around that.

Answer (score -1):

You should try **octopus gem** which allows following features

**Replication**

**sharding**

**Replication + Sharding**

https://github.com/thiagopradi/octopus

Comment: This should be posted as a comment, not as an answer.